# Как реализовать разбивку на группы букв

Tags: java

[image: Скрин]я сделал что есть строка которая шифрует текст.
Как сделать чтобы можно разбивку по группам задавал пользователь. То есть захотел на 4 буквы сделал на 4, захотел на 5 то на 5

```
public class Helper {
 
    private static String getEncryptedStr(String source) {
        StringBuilder charBox = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length() - 1; i += 2) {
            charBox.append(source.charAt(i + 1));
            charBox.append(source.charAt(i));
        }
        return charBox.toString();
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ss = "андрей пошёл в магазин"; // исходное сообщение
        System.out.println(getEncryptedStr(ss)); // зашифрованное 
        System.out.println(getEncryptedStr(getEncryptedStr(ss)));  // зашифрованное и расшифрованное = исходному
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества, смотрите оно шифрует текст и выводит в довольном порядке, а как сделать например  чтобы пользователь сам вводил на сколько  букв он хочет разбить слова.

Comment: @Духсообщества,добавил скрины, как конкретно звучит задание и описане к нему

Comment: ну добавляй пробел после нужного количества букв и все. Неужели сложно дотумкать!?

Comment: @Эникейщик можна пожалуйста дописать. А то я что то не понял

Comment: что именно не понял?

Comment: @Эникейщик как мне пробелы помогут устанавлить длину разбивки ?

Comment: пробелы это и есть разбивка. Пустое место между группами по 4 буквы это пробел и есть.

Comment: @Эникейщик мне надо чтобы я сам выбирал сколько букв будет в одной группе

Comment: я это понял. алгоритм и способ разбивки от этого не меняется

Comment: @Эникейщик, можете тогда написать как это будет выглядеть пожалуйста

Comment: что "это"? N символов пробел N символов пробел ....

Comment: Разве не лучше шифровать с помощью исключающего или. 
Типа ключ key и str: str^key. А строку можно поделить  сотнями способами , ну тот же split и добавить, N(через N ставить пробелы),  или в StringBuilder наверное чет есть. Я просто на строки пока что не особо обращал внимания

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Убрать все лишние небуквенные символы, например, используя `String::replaceAll`, с классом `\P{L}`, обозначающим все не-буквенные символы`:

```java
String str = "пусть будет так, как мы хотели";
String raw = str.replaceAll("\\P{L}", ""); // пустьбудеттаккакмыхотели
```

2. Перевернуть строку, используя `StringBuilder::reverse`:

```java
raw = new StringBuilder(raw).reverse().toString(); // илетохымкаккаттедубьтсуп
```

3. Разбить строку на группы из n символов, используя `String::split` с "магическим" регулярным выражением `(?<=\G.{n})`, которое обозначает *предыдущее* совпадение, после которого идут *n* символов, затем полученный массив можно объединить при помощи `String::join`:

```java
int n = 4;
String result = String.join(" ", raw.split("(?<=\\G.{" + n +"})"));
// илет охым какк атте дубь тсуп
// илето хымка ккатт едубь тсуп - для n = 5
```

---

```java
private static String encrypt(String str, int n) {
    String raw = new StringBuilder(str.replaceAll("\\P{L}", ""))
        .reverse().toString();
        
    return String.join(" ", raw.split("(?<=\\G.{" + n +"})"));
}
```

Comment: А можно к вам ещё обратится ща помощью?

Comment: Смотря по какому вопросу

Comment: Тоже шифрование, только другим способом, прикрепил скриншот

Comment: Буду очень признателен

Comment: 1. Для нового способа шифрования создайте новый вопрос 2. Откуда должны браться "незначащие буквы"?

Comment: Там строка есть как и в 1 задании 
Пусть будет так как мы хотели

Comment: Для нового вопроса нужны наработки так не принимает вопрос